# PGFPLOT Externalization not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, pgfplotstable

I am trying to externalize PGF Plot to be saved as EPS file using latex and enabled shell-escape.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{external}
    \tikzexternalize%[prefix=fig/]
    \tikzset{external/system call={latex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -jobname="\image" "\texsource" ; dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi ; ps2eps -f "\image".ps && mv "\image".eps "\image"}} 

    \pgfplotsset{ compat=1.8,  tick label style={font=\small},  label style={font=\small}, legend style={font=\footnotesize}}
    \tikzexternalize[prefix=fig/] 
    \title{\LaTeX\ plots with \texttt{tikz} and \texttt{pgfplots}}
    \author{Roel Van Beeumen}
    \date{April 17, 2012}

    \begin{document}
    %\tikzsetnextfilename{filename}
    \tikzset{external/force remake}
    \maketitle


    % == A first plot ======================================== %
    \section{A first plot}

    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    % -------------------------------------------------------- %
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sqrt{|x|}$, axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left, ymax=2.1,xmax=4.4]
    \addplot[blue,mark=none,domain=-4:4,samples=201] {sqrt(abs(x))};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % -------------------------------------------------------- %
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[2]



    % == A second plot ======================================= %
    \section{A second plot}

    \lipsum[3]
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    % -------------------------------------------------------- %
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[xlabel=Dof,ylabel=Error,width=\textwidth]
    \addplot file{datafile1a.dat};
    \addplot file{datafile1b.dat};
    \legend{Case 1,Case 2}
    \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % -------------------------------------------------------- %
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[4-5]



    % == A third plot ======================================== %
    \section{A third plot}

    \lipsum[6]
    \begin{figure}[hbtp]
    \centering
    % -------------------------------------------------------- %
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[xlabel=Dof,ylabel=Error,width=\textwidth]
    \addplot table[x=dof1,y=error1] {datafile2.dat};
    \addplot table[x=dof2,y=error2] {datafile2.dat};
    \legend{Case 1,Case 2}
    \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % -------------------------------------------------------- %
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[7]


    \end{document}
```

However, on executing this with latex -shell-escape in Linux Mint 16 with TeX Live 2013, I get the following error for each plot.

**! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'latex -shell-escape -interaction=
nonstopmode -jobname="untitled-1-figure2" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{untitled-1}
\input{untitled-1}" ; dvips -o "untitled-1-figure2".ps "untitled-1-figure2".dvi
 ; ps2eps -f "untitled-1-figure2".ps && mv "untitled-1-figure2".eps "untitled-1
-figure2"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'untitled-1-figure2' (expecte
d one of epsi:eps:ps). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pd
flatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18'
 or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can
 be found in 'untitled-1-figure2.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset
 the picture.**

However, if I just press **Return** key, it generates EPS files successfully. I tried a lot of trials, but no luck. Please help me.

Comment: It is to be expected that either `untitled-1-figure2.log` contains hints on what went wrong or that `untitled-1.log` contains more information. Could you take a look into these two log files and append suspicious snippets?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have you had a chance to check the log files yet, as Christian suggested?